# Is producing porn partially legal in India?

Tags: india, indian-penal-code

Just now I am browsing videos on free porn streaming sites,
but I saw so many homemade porn contents are produced in India itself.

But According to Indian Penal Codes, Making porn in India is illegal. Why are producers not prosecuted for it?

Is producing porn partially legal in India?

Comment: Robbing banks is illegal: people still do it.

Comment: People who does robbing banks are not roaming free like who produce homemade porn. Law is taking action on people who robbed banks.

Comment: Please clarify if your question is: Is making porn in India illegal? Or: Making porn in India is illegal. Why are producers not prosecuted for it?

Comment: It seems to me quite clearly to be on the legal status of porn production in India: the observation that people seem to do it brazenly and overtly seems merely to have presented the inspiration for it.